# Difference between tools with same name in ArcGIS 3D Analyst and Spatial Analyst toolboxes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, 3d-analyst, arctoolbox

There are several of the same tools within the 3D Analyst and Spatial Analyst toolboxes (for example, Reclassify and Visibility).

Is the same tool being accessed regardless of whether it is found within the 3D Analyst or Spatial Analyst toolboxes?

Comment: Have you tried taking one of your example tools and comparing their documentation?  If it is different, especially in the parameters offered, then I think it is safe to assume that they are different.  Otherwise, I suspect they are the same and just unlocked by either of the two extensions.

Comment: I have always assumed it was the latter (from PolyGeo's comment). I've run some of them and gotten the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raster interpolation, reclassification, math, and surface analysis tools in 3D Analyst that have the same name as their Spatial Analyst counterparts are using the same underyling functions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the contour tool using each once and did get different results! (the same input parameters were available) It was on a raster with fairly low resolution and one had boxier results than the other.